# Find Max value of column from all tables with that column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to show the MAX of a date field, that several of my tables have in my database.

Answer (score 2):

```
select max(col)
from (select max(col) from t1
      union all
      select max(col) from t2
      union all
      ...
      select max(col) from tn)
```

Comment: I have over 300 tables, in my database. Is there an easier option, so I dont have to union all those tables

Comment: Some "script" solution perhaps? But why do you have so many similar tables?

Comment: the tables all have a Update_Date field, i just want to see when each table was last updated